# OpenCV Image Processing GUI: TypeError: on_click_diff_per_button() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, tkinter

I am creating an OpenCV GUI for Image Processing. I have two image file folder. One is the Sample Image folder and the other is a reference file folder. I am importing both images in the frame and sample frame with the help of `filedialog.askopenfilename`. Now it is showing in two different frames. I am trying to connect the elements of both the frames with the 3rd frame so that it can display the image difference between two images.While performing the operation, I am getting the following error:

**ERROR:**

```
select button clicked
upload button clicked
select Sample button clicked
upload Sample button clicked
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CTPL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/CTPL/PycharmProjects/TempMatching/OpenCV_GUI_try2.py", line 280, in <lambda>
    select_button = tk.Button(frame5, text='Difference', command=lambda: difference_button.on_click_diff_per_button(Difference_per_label))
TypeError: on_click_diff_per_button() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

The python script I have applied is as shown below:

[**ERROR IMAGE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBnMj.jpg)

I have highlighted the Error portion in the above image.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import glob
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity
class Button:

    def __init__(self, root, frame2):
        self.root = root
        self.frame2 = frame2
        self.radio_var = tk.IntVar()
        self.path_selected = 'none'
        self.paths = []
        self.radio_handle = []
        self.check_value = []

    def on_click_select_button(self, fname_label):
        print('select button clicked')
        fileType = [('jpg/png file', ('*.jpg', '*.png'))]
        self.path_selected = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType)
        fname_label['text'] = os.path.basename(self.path_selected)

    def on_click_upload_button(self, path='None', image='None'):
        print('upload button clicked')

        if path == 'None':
            path = self.path_selected
        else:
            cv2.imwrite(path, image)

        if path in self.paths:
            messagebox.showerror('Upload Error', '"'
                                 + path
                                 + '"' + ' is already uploaded.')
        else:
            self.paths.append(path)
            self.create_radio_button(path)

    def on_click_show_button(self):
        print('showButton clicked')
        image = cv2.imread(self.paths[self.radio_var.get()])
        file_name = os.path.basename(self.paths[self.radio_var.get()])
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)
        path = 'images/' + name + '_' + ext

        # cv2.imwrite(path, image)
        self.open_image_window(path, image)

    def create_radio_button(self, path):

        image = cv2.imread(path)
        # image = cv2.resize(image,(120,120))
        image = self.scale_to_height(image, 120)
        image_tk = self.to_tk_image(image)

        radio_button = tk.Radiobutton(self.frame2, image=image_tk,
                                      value=len(self.radio_handle),
                                      variable=self.radio_var)
        self.radio_var.set(0)
        self.radio_handle.append(radio_button)
        self.check_value.append(self.radio_var)

        radio_button.grid(row=(len(self.radio_handle) - 1) // 3,
                          column=(len(self.radio_handle) - 1) % 3)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def open_image_window(self, path, image):

        if image.shape[0] > 300:
            image = self.scale_to_height(image, 300)

        img_win = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        fname = os.path.basename(path)
        img_win.title(fname)
        img_canvas = tk.Canvas(img_win, width=image.shape[1],
                               height=image.shape[0])
        img_canvas.pack()
        image_tk = self.to_tk_image(image)
        img_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=image_tk, anchor='nw')

        uploadButton2 = tk.Button(img_win, text='upload',
                                  command=lambda: self.on_click_upload_button(path, image))
        uploadButton2.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()
    def to_tk_image(self, image_bgr):
        image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image_pil = Image.fromarray(image_rgb)
        image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_pil)
        return image_tk
    def scale_to_height(self, img, height):
        scale = height / img.shape[0]
        return cv2.resize(img, dsize=None, fx=scale, fy=scale)
class Sample_Button:
    def __init__(self, root, frame4):
        self.Sample_root = root
        self.frame4 = frame4
        self.Sample_radio_var = tk.IntVar()
        self.Sample_path_selected = 'none'
        self.Sample_paths = []
        self.Sample_radio_handle = []
        self.Sample_check_value = []

    def on_click_select_button_Sample(self, Sample_fname_label):
        print('select Sample button clicked')
        Sample_fileType = [('jpg/png file', ('*.jpg', '*.png'))]
        self.Sample_path_selected = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=Sample_fileType)
        Sample_fname_label['text'] = os.path.basename(self.Sample_path_selected)

    def on_click_upload_button_Sample(self, Sample_path='None', Sample_image='None'):
        print('upload Sample button clicked')

        if Sample_path == 'None':
            Sample_path = self.Sample_path_selected
        else:
            cv2.imwrite(Sample_path, Sample_image)

        if Sample_path in self.Sample_paths:
            messagebox.showerror('Upload Error', '"'
                                 + Sample_path
                                 + '"' + ' Sample is already uploaded.')
        else:
            self.Sample_paths.append(Sample_path)
            self.create_Sample_radio_button(Sample_path)

    def on_click_show_button_Sample(self):
        print('show Sample Button clicked')
        Sample_image = cv2.imread(self.Sample_paths[self.Sample_radio_var.get()])
        Sample_file_name = os.path.basename(self.Sample_paths[self.Sample_radio_var.get()])
        Sample_name, ext = os.path.splitext(Sample_file_name)
        Sample_path = 'Sample_images/' + Sample_name + '_' + ext


    def create_Sample_radio_button(self, Sample_path):
        Sample_image = cv2.imread(Sample_path)
        Sample_image = self.scale_to_height_Sample(Sample_image, 120)
        Sample_image_tk = self.Sample_to_tk_image(Sample_image)

        Sample_radio_button = tk.Radiobutton(self.frame4, image=Sample_image_tk,
                                      value=len(self.Sample_radio_handle),
                                      variable=self.Sample_radio_var)
        self.Sample_radio_var.set(0)
        self.Sample_radio_handle.append(Sample_radio_button)
        self.Sample_check_value.append(self.Sample_radio_var)

        Sample_radio_button.grid(row=(len(self.Sample_radio_handle) - 1) // 3,
                          column=(len(self.Sample_radio_handle) - 1) % 3)
        self.Sample_root.mainloop()

    def Sample_to_tk_image(self, Sample_image_bgr):
        Sample_image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(Sample_image_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        Sample_image_pil = Image.fromarray(Sample_image_rgb)
        Sample_image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Sample_image_pil)
        return Sample_image_tk

    def scale_to_height_Sample(self, Sample_img, height):
        scale = height / Sample_img.shape[0]
        return cv2.resize(Sample_img, dsize=None, fx=scale, fy=scale)

class Difference_Button(Button, Sample_Button):
    def on_click_diff_per_button(self):
        print('select Difference button clicked')

        Sample_image = cv2.imread(self.Sample_paths[self.Sample_radio_var.get()])
        print(Sample_image)
        image = cv2.imread(self.paths[self.radio_var.get()])
        print(image)
        #for x in range(7):
        Greyscale_Sample_image = cv2.cvtColor(Sample_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        Greyscale_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

        (score, diff) = structural_similarity(Greyscale_image, Greyscale_Sample_image, full=True)  # bw_
        print("Image similarity %ge =", score * 100)

        diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")

        cv2.imshow('diff', diff)
        cv2.waitKey()

    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.makedirs('images', exist_ok=True)
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Image GUI')
    root.geometry('1280x960')
    pw_left = tk.Frame(root, relief='ridge', borderwidth=4)
    pw_left.pack(side='left', anchor='nw')
    pw_right = tk.Frame(root, relief='ridge', borderwidth=4)
    pw_right.pack(side='left', anchor='nw')
    frame1 = tk.Frame(pw_left, bd=2, relief="ridge")
    frame1.pack()
    frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(pw_right, bd=2, text='Uploaded images')
    frame2.pack(side='left', anchor='nw')
    button = Button(root, frame2)
    label = tk.Label(frame1, text='File:')
    label.grid(row=0, column=0)
    file_name_label = tk.Label(frame1, text='-----not selected-----', width=20, bg='white')
    file_name_label.grid(row=0, column=1)
    select_button = tk.Button(frame1, text='select', command=lambda: button.on_click_select_button(file_name_label))
    select_button.grid(row=0, column=2)
    uploadButton = tk.Button(frame1, text='Upload',
                             command=lambda: button.on_click_upload_button())
    uploadButton.grid(row=0, column=3)
    os.makedirs('Sample_images', exist_ok=True)
    pw_left = tk.Frame(root, relief='ridge', borderwidth=4)
    pw_left.pack(side='left', anchor='nw')
    pw_right = tk.Frame(root, relief='ridge', borderwidth=4)
    pw_right.pack(side='left', anchor='nw')
    frame3 = tk.Frame(pw_left, bd=2, relief="ridge")
    frame3.pack()
    frame4 = tk.LabelFrame(pw_right, bd=2, text='Uploaded Sample images')
    frame4.pack(side='right', anchor='nw')


    Sample_button = Sample_Button(root, frame4)
    Sample_label = tk.Label(frame3, text='Sample File:')
    Sample_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
    Sample_file_name_label = tk.Label(frame3, text='-----not selected-----', width=20, bg='white')
    Sample_file_name_label.grid(row=0, column=1)
    Sample_select_button = tk.Button(frame3, text='select',
                                     command=lambda: Sample_button.on_click_select_button_Sample(
                                         Sample_file_name_label))
    Sample_select_button.grid(row=0, column=2)
    Sample_uploadButton = tk.Button(frame3, text='Upload',
                                    command=lambda: Sample_button.on_click_upload_button_Sample())
    Sample_uploadButton.grid(row=0, column=3)
    os.makedirs('Differece_images', exist_ok=True)
    pw_left = tk.Frame(root, relief='ridge', borderwidth=4)
    pw_left.pack(side='left', anchor='nw')
    pw_right = tk.Frame(root, relief='ridge', borderwidth=4)
    pw_right.pack(side='left', anchor='nw')
    frame5 = tk.Frame(pw_left, bd=2, relief="ridge")
    frame5.pack()
    frame6 = tk.LabelFrame(pw_right, bd=2, text='Uploaded images')
    frame6.pack(side='left', anchor='nw')

    difference_button = Difference_Button(root, frame6)
    Difference_per_label = tk.Label(frame5, text='Show Image Difference', width=20, bg='white')
    Difference_per_label.grid(row=0, column=1)
    img_diff_button = tk.Button(frame5, text='Difference', command=lambda: difference_button.on_click_diff_per_button(Difference_per_label))
    img_diff_button.grid(row=0, column=2)


    root.mainloop()
```

Kindly help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear enough:
`on_click_diff_per_button() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

How you define `on_click_diff_per_button()`:

```
    def on_click_diff_per_button(self):
        print('select Difference button clicked')
    ....
```

How you call that function:

```
select_button = tk.Button(frame5, text='Difference', command=lambda: difference_button.on_click_diff_per_button(Difference_per_label))
```

You gave another parameter `Difference_per_label` except the button itself (`self`)

Comment: `    Difference_per_label = tk.Label(frame5, text='Show Image Difference', width=20, bg='white')
    Difference_per_label.grid(row=0, column=1)
    img_diff_button = tk.Button(frame5, text='Difference', command=lambda: difference_button.on_click_diff_per_button(Difference_per_label))
    img_diff_button.grid(row=0, column=2)`
here img_diff_button is ineterconnected with  Difference_per_label

Comment: Your function `on_click_diff_per_button` takes no other parameters except the button itself as `self`. That's the reason.

Comment: What @lincr is trying to say, that you have whether to have ``def on_click_diff_per_button(self, varName):`` or ``select_button = tk.Button(frame5, text='Difference', command=lambda: difference_button.on_click_diff_per_button())`` since you don't use value of ``Difference_per_label`` in method later anyway.